# Serial communication error in objective-C: Resource busy

Tags: objective-c, c, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm writing some code which purpose is to read values send by an ECG. 
The ECG sends values read by it's sensors through a serial connection and (as a start) all the program has to do is read the input and display it in a text view.

However I have hit a wall and can't seem to solve the following two problems:

I get the following error a lot of the times I try to connect with the ECG: Unable to open /dev/tty.usbserial.A700eLwM - : **Resource busy**. 
The port is not being used by any other applications but the ECG is sending numbers.
Can I somehow tell the OS that whatever is happening and whoever is using that port I want to have full control of the port?

My code is as follows:

```
fd = open("/dev/tty.usbserial-A700eLwM", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

[textView insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Port status: %f\n", fd]];

if (fd == -1)
{
    /*
     * Could not open the port.
     */

    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/tty.usbserial.A700eLwM - ");

}
    else {
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
}
```

My second problem is that I don't quite understand how I can buffer the reading into a string or integer variable and send it to the text view.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you've activated the serial port as a network device in Network Preferences. If it's listed there, select it and use the cogwheel menu item "mark as inactive".

For your second problem there's a lot of other matching questions on the site, search for it.